# URL variable to Session variable (using GET method)

Tags: php, url, get, session-variables

I am trying to store a value obtained from a URL variable into a SESSION variable.

Here is the URL:

```
<a href="webpage.php?store=<?php echo 'Ace'; ?>">Ace Hardware</a>
```

Here is the SESSION coding, which retrieves the variable, but loses the variable value upon leaving the page.

```
$_SESSION["store"] = $_GET["store"];
$shopByStore = $_SESSION["store"];
```

If I plug in the value in quotes as it is below (see "Ace" in code below), it works. But it doesn't work in the code above using the GET method ($_GET["store"])

```
$_SESSION["store"] = "Ace";
$shopByStore = $_SESSION["store"];
```

Comment: Did you started the `session` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you override the `$_SESSION["store"]` with the `$_GET["store"]` each time whether the get request exists or not, so it basically only uses `$_GET["store"]`.  You could use this instead:

```
if (isset($_GET["store"])) {
    $_SESSION["store"] = $_GET["store"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At first you need to start the `session` and then make sure it's already not stored in the `session` (if it's passed in the `$_GET`) and if not already saved in the `session` then store it:

```
// The first line in your script
session_start();

if (isset($_GET["store"])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION["store"])) {
        $_SESSION["store"] = $_GET["store"];
    }
}
```

Read more on [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).